# Visual artifacts on a multithreaded ray-tracing

Tags: c++, multithreading, raytracing

I have been trying to port a RayTracer from a single thread version to a multithrea one. On most cases, it work as expected, but on two test cases, problems arise. In one, where there is a big triangle that covers most of the  screen, in some executions, its color, blue, turns into black

In the other case, the problem always happens. The image that has a blue plane as the background, should be a smooth one. However this is what happens in a MT execution: https://postimg.cc/image/erm55m6ff/

If I tell my program to print some debugging information, this is what is produced:

> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1
>
> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1
>
> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1
>
> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1

In other words, it is running the ray-tracing procedure over a single pixel four times for some unknown reason. This does not happen to all the pixels m neither is a constant one. When I run again, the printed info will show one a single

> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1

line, but this will happen with other pixels. In other words, it's variable and it can be noted visually.

This is the third time a open a thread here to discuss here. I received a bunch of suggestions that I followed. From these I realized that it's not a algorithm thing, because I tried two different ones. One that splits the screen in both halfs and one that gives each thread a different pixel (i.e thread0 -> pixel0, thread1 -> pixel1, thread0 -> pixel2, thread1 -> pixel 3, etc). The artifacts happens in both algorithms, although they vary a little bit (the split screen one produces less artifacts on the top of the screen, as the link I posted before shows).

I followed the suggestion of allowing only one thread to render each time. Executed the tests with both algorithms, and in both there was no artifacts.

Followed the suggestion of using completely separate copies of the data. Actually the original version used a single instance of an object RayTracer, but that instance was send to each thread, where it executed the ray-tracing subroutine. So it created all the needed data for each different thread, but there was a single memory pool where the pixel color were written. So while there was shared memory, there never was the case of a thread writing to a same position of this shared memory area that the other thread did. Ever. That's way I never was worried about using things as locks, semaphores or mutex. 
Anyway, I started to use two different instances, and so two different memory pools. Adjusted a couple of counters in the ray-tracing procedure and started to doing the file writing with a for loop, writing a pixel from thread 0 followed by pixel of thread 1, using the "put" member function (before I did a single call to "write" member function, taking advantage of a single memory pool).
It did not work either.

Summoning what I have here it is a visual artifact induced by MT that was possible to realize that:

1) Is not related the choice of the algorithms used.
2) If only a single thread works, I obtain no artifacts. Which probably means the problem is not on the algorithm.
3) It's not lock related. First there never really was memory sharing, since the common memory pool never had a single position accessed by both threads.

So what can be? I remember a comment about non thread safe API, but I am only using standard c++ stuff (iostream, string, etc...). Might it be a pthread bug? I am using a quite old OS, compiler and libraries (about ten years old). I accept ANY suggestions!

Comment: It is more likely to be a bug in your code than a pthread bug. You say you did this that and the other, but who is to say you did not make any mistakes with that? Describing what you did doesn't help us figure out what mistakes you may have made. Can you post a code example that reproduces the error?

Comment: No I cannot do so (how I would do with something so complex). Nonetheless, I posted some code in a previous post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401206/multithreading-raytracer-generating-artifacts-with-two-different-algorithms